# Block elements take full width when text wraps on to two lines

Tags: text, width, line, block

I'm basically just curious about this because I see it all the time and no one I have spoken to seems to know if there is a solution.

Usually when I come across this its for a fancy looking `<a>` button with a background on it and is display block or inline block.

The issue is this: say you have a button inside a div that has a specific width, let's say `160px`, and you have a display block or inline-block `<a>` inside, if the text inside the `<a>` can't all fit on one line it wraps on to two as you would expect but now that it is on two lines it no longer really needs to take up the full width of the div but it does!

I'm not really that surprised that this happens but I was wondering if anyone knew of a CSS or even JavaScript solution that fixes this?

Code:

```
<div style="width: 160px; padding: 10px; background: blue;">
  <a href="#" style="background: red; display: block;">Test with a longwrappingword</a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb6es/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb6es/3/) work for you?

```
<div style="width: 160px; padding: 10px; background: blue;">
  <a href="#" style="background: red; display: table; width: 1%">Test with a longwrappingword</a>
</div>
<span style="padding-left:130px">^ Where the element COULD end if it wanted to</span>
```

Comment: It's still not perfect though, it causes the text to break on to two lines when it doesn't need to either strangely. Like if the surrounding div was wider or had no width defined. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb6es/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/UPxZm/

```
<div style="width: 160px; padding: 10px; background: blue;">
  <a id="block" href="#" style="background: red; display: block;">Test with a longwrappingword</a>
</div>

<script>
var $block = $('#block');
var orig = $block.html();
var index = orig.lastIndexOf(' ') || -1;
var longword = orig.substring(index + 1, orig.length);

$block.html(orig + longword);
var wanted_width = $block[0].scrollWidth / 2;
$block.html(orig);
$block.width(wanted_width);
</script>
```

Comment: Far from ideal, there have to be less clumsy ways to do it, but without javascript I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? I added a width attribute to anchor.

```
<div style="width: 160px; padding: 10px; background: blue;">
  <a href="#" style="background: red; display: block; width: 100px;">Test with a longwrappingword</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That does work but I want it to be dynamic so it will work with any length of text.